# Exclude character from being returned in array

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex function:

```
function getMatches($string_content) {
    $matches = array();

    preg_match_all('/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/', $string_content, $matches);

    return $matches;
}
```

Right now, it returns an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => @test
        [1] => @test2
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [0] => test
        [1] => test2
    )
)
```

How can I make it *only return the matches without the @ symbol*?

Comment: take out the `@` from your regex expression: /([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/

Comment: `$matches[1]`? Why not?

Comment: That's how `preg_match_all()` works. `$matches[0]` will be an array containing all the whole strings that were matched. The captured items will be in `$matches[1]`. Simply change `return $matches;` to `return $matches[1];`.

Comment: @Amalmurali thats the correct answer as i stated.

Comment: @hwnd: Ooh yes, I'd missed that. +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this small tweak (you can inspect the matches in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/tJ1sY8/2)):

```
preg_match_all('~@\K\w+~', $string_content, $matches);
```

**Explanation**

- In your original regex, the parentheses around `([A-Za-z0-9_]+)` create a capture group. This is why the array contains a second element with index #1: this element contains the Group 1 captures.
- `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns. It is more efficient than using a lookbehind `(?<=@)`
- The `~` is just a small esthetic tweak—you can use any delimiter you like around your regex patttern.

Comment: Why change the sides of the regex expression from slashes to ~?

Comment: You don't have to change the `/` to `~`, but I recommend you do it as a matter of habit. In PHP you can use whatever delimiter you like around the regex, and the `/` is just a convention from Perl (though Perl also allows other delimiters). The `/` is quite inconvenient because it forces you to escape every forward slash: for instance, you have to write `/http:\/\/google\//`, whereas another delimiter lets you do `~http://google/~` It is much cleaner. Of course if your regex contains a `~` then you need to escape it—or use another delimiter, for instance `#` or `%`

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. Just waiting for the cooldown so I can mark this as correct.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Added that delimiter story to the answer, and it is also well-explained at the top of this [article about php regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html). :)

Comment: Hey FYI I further shortened the solution to `@\K\w+` since `\w` is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9]` Let me know if you have other questions. :)

Comment: Note that you'd need `$matches[0]` instead of `$matches` (as written in the OP).

Comment: @AmalMurali Yes, you're right. I've been assuming that he understands how to get things out of an array and just wanted a simpler one. :)

Answer (score 2):

Return `$matches[1]` instead of `$matches`.

That will give you the first capture group instead of all matches.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\K` in your regex to avoid `@` in the final result and you don't need to capture anything,

```
preg_match_all('~@\K[A-Za-z0-9_]+~', $string_content, $matches);
```

OR

Use a lookbehind,

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=@)[A-Za-z0-9_]+~', $string_content, $matches);
```

DEMO

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=@)` REgex engine sets the matching marker just after to the `@` symbol.
- `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` Matches one or more word characters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any change in your regular expression, simply refer to capturing group `#1`, which would be `$matches[1]` to print the match result from your capturing group, excluding `@` from your array matches.

Your code would look like this:

```
function getMatches($string_content) {
    preg_match_all('/@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/', $string_content, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
print_r(getMatches('foo bar @test baz @test2 quz'));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => test2
)
```